# Function $f(t), 0\leq t\leq 1$ which has a long "toe" and "shoulder"

Tags: functions

I'm trying to construct a function that smoothly goes from $f(0)=0$ to $f(1)=1$, and pretty much looks like $e^t-1$ for small $t$, and conversely looks like $1-(e^{1-t}-1)$ for large (close to $1$) $t$. And it should be symmetrical, $f(1-t)=1-f(t)$ with $f(.5)=.5$ at the midpoint. And it would be nice if $f$ had some parameter, call it $k$, that controlled the size of the toe and shoulder regions. That is, something like $k=0$ gives you a straight line $f(t)=t$, up to $k=\infty$ gives you a step function at $.5$ (or anything like that).

Seems like it should be pretty easy to do, but I unexpectedly stymied myself while trying (and I couldn't get google to cough it up, either). This $f$ is just for the $t$-parameter of a bezier curve. I want the curve to stay pretty close to its control-point endpoints for most of the $0\leq t\leq 1$ range, while quickly moving between them during the middle part. So the exact mathematical function isn't particularly important; just the general toe-and-shoulder shape (plus the few other constraints mentioned above).

**E d i t
---------------**
Thanks, guys, for your comments and answer.

Actually, it's as easy to construct as I'd originally anticipated, but I didn't manage to see it until after I wrote the question. In general, if you just have an $f(t)$ that grows more slowly than linearly, and for which $f(.5)=.5$, then use that for $0\leq t\leq .5$, and simply use $1-f(1-t)$ for $.5\leq t\leq1$. And my question suggests $f(t)=e^t-1$, which we can simply "normalize" so that $f(t)=\frac{e^t-1}{2(e^{.5}-1)}$ is $.5$ at $t=.5$.

But it's even easier choosing $f(t)=t^n/(2(.5^n))=(2t)^n/2$ (integer $n$ not necessary). And here's what that looks like for $n=5$...
[image]

Comment: Is $x^{2(1-x)}$ a candidate ?

Comment: some movement of $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$  works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) springs to mind immediately. This is similar to $e^x-1$ for $x \to 0$ and is also symmetric.

[image]

The general formula of this function is
$$f(x) = ke^{-a(x-b)^2}$$
for the function that I plotted above, $k = 0.5, a = 20$ and $b = 0.5$. $b$ controls the axis of symmetry, $k$ controls the peak height and $a$ controls the overall 'spread' of the function.

Comment: Thanks @AniruddhaDeb That doesn't actually demonstrate the "symmetrical" behavior, now illustrated above, that I was looking for. But I could use your $fx)$ for the $0\leq x\leq .5$ left-hand-side, and then use $1-f(1-x)$  for the rhs, as discussed above in the edit. Yours has all the "knobs"/parameters necessary for my necessary constraints and desired control.

Comment: @JohnForkosh 'Symmetry' in a function about $a$ is interpreted as $f(x) = f(a-x)$, which is what i assumed from your initial question. You might also want to have a look at the error function, which seems to satisfy your edited question https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Yeah, usually interpreted that way, but I explicitly said, _"should be symmetrical, $f(1−t)=1−f(t)$"_, immediately following "symmetrical" with my intended meaning. Besides, given your mention of Higgs in your profile, you should be more than a little familiar with all kinds of goofy symmetries **:)**